# Can the Snorlax on route 7 be female?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have been soft resetting for a while. If it can be female what are the odds of it being female.

Comment: I just got one. I crited it so it died >: (

Comment: I did the same thing soft resetting for a shiny Lugia in Soulsilver. One-shot crit when I finally got a shiny...

Comment: I just did it again aaarghhh >:'(

Comment: Should be able to get False Swipe already; Pancham can learn it and it's in the lab with doctor sycamore in Lumoise

Comment: I got fed up and caught a sword thingy, however it was low level and did too little damage so I tried weakening the Snorlax with my Frogadier but it crit killed it twice more. FMLuck. I even kept track of Males vs Females seen. It came out as 7.5 male to 1 female. With such a low number of test runs I believe it would work out as the 7 males to 1 female had I continued soft resetting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Snorlax on Route 7 can be female. The odds of it being so is quite low however, 12.5% (1 in 8).

You can see more [here](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/143.shtml)